# Large APK size when using NDK , how to reduce android app (APK) size?

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, apk

I have developed a One Android application. Its APK size is 8MB. Can anyone tell me how to reduce the APK size when using NDK in my App? TIA

Comment: Have you checked this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549738/reduce-apk-size-using-patch-and-update-on-google-play-store/49558974#49558974) , [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826626/how-to-reduce-android-apk-size/49573117#49573117) , [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529504/how-to-reduce-apk-size-when-using-play-services-gcm/49572661#49572661)?

Comment: @Sagar already checked this. playstore app size is 8Mb. raw size is 9.6 Mb. release size is 9.0 mB.. but still i want to reduce apk size.

Comment: Check the updated comment

Comment: Did you specify an abiFilter in your gradle script? Otherwise you'll probably end up building for all ABIs, which you may not need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting multiple architectures, using [App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/) will automatically split your APKs for you so your app only contains the libraries needed for the given device.

Answer (score 0):

I think configuring multiple apks for screen densities or ABIs might help you.

Documentation here : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits

Comment: I would look instead at the Android App Bundle (just announced by Google), which basically handles the splits for you: http://g.co/androidappbundle

Comment: @Pierre yesterday received mail from google about androidappbundle. thats awesome. :p